# Integration of the acceleration of a particle

Tags: calculus

One thing I don't understand is if we have $a(t)= \frac{dv}{dt}$ and we integrate both sides with respect to $t$ we get

$$\int_0^t a(t) dt=\int_{v_0}^vdv$$

But I don't get why the lower bound is $v_0$ and the upper bound is $v$. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: This is bad notation. It is usually better to have a different variable in your integration limits. You should have limits of $0$ and $t$ in both integrals, otherwise "integrating both sides" isn't properly happening. The result you should find is that

$$\int_0^t a(t)\, dt = v(t)-v(0),$$

where $v(0)$ is often written as $v_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $v=v(t)$.

One can rewrite your equality as $$\int_0^t a(t) dt=\int_0^t \frac{dv}{dt} dt=\int_{v(0)}^{v(t)}dv=\int_{v_0}^{v}dv$$

better notation would be $$\int_0^t a(t') dt'=\int_0^t \frac{dv}{dt'} dt'=\int_{v(0)}^{v(t)}dv$$

Comment: So because $dt$ cancels out in the second integral and it is now with respect to $dv$, we have to change the bounds?

Comment: Yes thats correct

Comment: Your "better notation" is the only one I'd really consider correct. $\int_{v_0}^v dv$ serves only to confuse people and although it's clear to me what is meant, I'd love to eliminate that usage for all time.